# Rank of matrix, linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, matrix-rank

The question:
Let A be an m*n matrix whose kernel is 0; that is, the only solution of the equation Ax=0 is x=0. What is the rank of A?

what did I think:
Ax is injective transformation, so the rank of A can't be m.

The answer is Rank(A)=n, but I don't know how to achieve it.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rank-nullity theorem states that $\operatorname {rk}A+\operatorname {nullity}A=n$.  Since the kernel is trivial,  $\operatorname {nullity}A=0$.

(Incidentally,  this means $m\ge n$.)